# How to create a dim background using the SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, background

I want to create a dim background that looks like the following picture, but it has a slight green tint to it.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DimBackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Dim background")
            }
            .frame(height: 350)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.green) // <- Not work
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(30)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
//        .background(.green) // <- Not work
    }
}

struct DimBackgroundVie_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DimBackgroundView()
    }
}
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk54b.png)

My expected:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oCIU.png)

I tries adding a green background before but it didn't work. Does anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: `.overlay(Color.green.opacity(0.5))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive this by using the ZStack or Overlay function to make the background image or color blurred or appear as a ThinMaterial.

Below, I'll provide answers to your question:

```
struct DimBackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            ZStack {
                //              Color.green
                Image("kenny-s-7qRM11Kmnh4-unsplash")
                
                Text("Click me")
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 350, alignment: .center)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            }
            .frame(height: 350)
            .cornerRadius(30)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Here, I'm using ZStack to make the background appear as ThinMaterial or blur.

Output :

https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2023-04-01-at-12.20.49-PM.png